# The option "Print all linked documents" in Internet Explorer 11 does not print all linked documents

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, internet-explorer-11

I manage a website which provides a resume management service for recruiters.

We have a feature that allows the end user to print a batch of resumes.  This is accomplished by rendering a web page that contains a series of links to all of the resumes they had previously selected.  This page is purposefully composed of very simple HTML.

They are instructed to (in Internet Explorer) click a link to open the standard print dialog.

In the print dialog, they click on the Options tab, and check the box to "Print all linked documents".  As you can imagine, when they hit "Print" the end result is that all the resumes linked from that page are printed.

This feature has been around since the days of Internet Explorer 7 and had always worked OK.

The feature is also not frequently used.  We just got a complaint from a client saying that when they attempted to print a batch of 25 resumes, only a "handful" of resumes printed.  They had just upgraded to Internet Explorer 11.  Previously they had been printing without issue.

I was able to duplicate this behavior on my machine and a couple of other workstations in our office.  A "handful" of resumes is as accurate a way as possible of describing the situation:  It seems that an arbitrary number of linked documents will be printed (usually less than 12, but never the full 25).

On some purposefully outdated dev images which have IE 7, 8, 9 and 10 I was able to print all documents as expected from the same web page as the failure case.

Observing the HTTP traffic in Fiddler shows that immediately upon clicking the "Print" button all 25 documents are requested from the server, and all responses contain 200 status codes and the correct content.

Further, in Internet Explorer 11 I was able to manually click into each link and print each of the 25 resumes without issue.  So it does not appear to be that it halts on an unprintable document.

Adding our site to the list of "Compatibility View" sites does not change the behavior.

I could reproduce the failure case using IE 11 on a few other arbitrarily chosen websites.

I'm not able to find any information on this problem elsewhere.  **Does anyone know if this is a known issue and/or if there is a fix?**

If you want to try it out for yourself, here is a simple test case:

http://s.co.tt/misc/test_print_linked_docs/test_25_links.html

Thanks for your time!

Comment: We have this issue as well which is quite a pain, as it was a handy feature when it worked. I don't suppose you've resolved it?

Comment: Sorry Dale, wish I could say that I had.  Please let me know if you find a solution, though!

Answer (score 1):

First, the "Low" folder is needed as a temporary working folder for the HTML pages being generated and printed from IE.

Start by bringing up a command prompt (`run -> cmd`), making sure you DO NOT run with elevated permissions (otherwise it will do this for your local admin account, which won’t help you).

At the command prompt, run the following command:

```
mkdir %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Low
```

This will create the necessary Low folder in the right place, which is almost certainly absent otherwise.

Other posts I read suggested this was enough, but it isn’t. The newly created ‘Low’ folder won’t work until you run a further command which sets the integrity level of this folder such that IE can use it (IE7 introduced a new protected mode, [which you can read more about here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx)).

So at the same prompt, run the following command:

```
icacls %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Low /setintegritylevel low
```

Having done this, restart IE, and you should find print preview and printing itself now works :) Now I just need to correct the 10 systems I already have set up with this little menace of a problem.

Good luck! :)